# if else statement has no effect - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, if-statement, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal box that contains a signup form. I've added some code that makes the modal box disappear when the submit button is pressed:

```
$(".dismiss-signup-modal").click(function () {
    jQuery('#signup_modal').modal('hide'); }
});
```

This works fine but I want to make the modal box stay where it is if the phone number field of the signup form is blank and only disappear if the phone number field has a value, something like this:

```
$(".dismiss-signup-modal").click(function () {

    if ($('.signup-phone').length > 0) {

    jQuery('#signup_modal').modal('hide'); }

    else {}
});
```

But the above code doesn't do anything, the modal box still disappears if the phone number field is left blank. I've tried every combination I can think of placing the if else statement outside the function or creating a new function or making the .signup-phone into a var but nothing works, any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to **check for the length of the value**..

But you were **checking for the existence of the jQuery object**
                   (If the element exists or not)

Supposed to be

```
   if( $('.signup-phone').val().length > 0 ) {
```

`$('.signup-phone').length` will always be greater than one, since that element is pressnton the page. So the condition is always true.

Comment: This. Btw, explaining why the `$('.signup-phone').length > 0` is wrong: Checking .length of a $(selector) is the same as *"Does this selector exists?"*. Therefore you need to get the value of the selector 9with `val()`, to see if was something written on it.

Comment: A better way to put it is that the number of elements matched by the selector is equal to the length of the jQuery object. By checking that it is greater than zero, it becomes an existence check.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Length on a JQuery object is different than length on a DOM element.  JQuery.length gives you the count of elements contained, not the length of the input elements value.  So:

```
$('.signup-phone').length;
```

should be a value of 1 because a single element was found with the class 'signup-phone'.  What you want is actually the length of the elements value instead:

```
$('.signup-phone').val().length;
```

Comment: Are you sure re: length being a function on the jQuery object? Might want to reread the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think `$('.signup-phone').length` is pointing toward the length of the element not the length of it value.

Maybe you could try this:

```
$(".dismiss-signup-modal").click(function () {

    if ($('.signup-phone').text.length > 0) {
    // or you could use 
    //if ($('.signup-phone').value.length > 0) {
    jQuery('#signup_modal').modal('hide'); }

    else {}
});
```

EDIT: By Element I mean JQuery Element(s //If the selector is a reference to more than one element).

Comment: What does that mean, the "length of the element"? A more accurate way of putting it is that the length of the jQuery object is equal to the number of elements it is currently matching.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding English is my foreign language and I could'nt find a better word to describe the JQuery Element(s).